# Reading a variable I set within Terminal osx 10.9

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to add a few temp variables within terminal.  I have tried this after searching the problem:

```
export value=10
export path=/Users/..../..../....., etc.
```

The problem is that I can't read the values back in order to confirm if they have stored correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting environment variables in OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Comment: Not really a duplicate -- the other question asks about how to set variables permanently, system-wide, and doesn't touch upon how to access their values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access your variables with `$variablename`.

Try e.g.

```
echo "$path"
```